# In Cypress, can you verify a table has rows prior to trying to traverse them?

Tags: cypress

I have a Cypress test in which I need to traverse the rows in a table - *if any rows exist*

My problem is that I don't know for certain if there are going to be any rows in the table.

The code below works fine - if there are rows in the table.

```
cy.get('tbody').find('tr').each($row => {
    //do stuff to each row
});
```

If there are no rows, I get the following error:

*Timed out retrying after 60000ms: Expected to find element: tr, but never found it.*

Can anyone tell me how to set this up such that if there are no rows it doesn't fail?

Thanks much

Comment: .should('have.exists')

Comment: Thanks.  So I can do something like this:

cy.get('tbody > tr').should('exist');


and it will fail if there are no rows - but I actually don't want it to fail if there are no rows.
It's strictly a prep thing - if there are no rows I just want it to skip this part.

Comment: If you want to add logic to the test (ideally you should be setting up separate tables on the page with and without rows, in my view), you could use document APIs to check for existence of rows. Something like this: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/document#Examples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can apply the `.find('tr')` query inside a callback, that way the test will not fail if there are no rows.

```js
cy.get('tbody').then($tbody => {
  const rows = $tbody.find('tr')
  if (rows.length) {
    cy.wrap(rows).each($row => {
```

But that's not at all best practice for testing, you should **set up the test** so that the table ***has rows***, then query as you did originally.

If you do it this way, any delay in loading the rows will cause you massive headaches.

---

**Example app**

Two tables #1 with no rows, #2 with rows

```html
<body>

  <table id="1">
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>

  <table id="2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>row 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

**Test**

```js
it('test row length', () => {
  cy.visit('http://127.0.0.1:5500/html/table-rows.html');

cy.get('table#1 tbody')
  .then($tbody => {
    const rows = $tbody.find('tr')
    return rows.length
  })
  .should('eq', 0)

cy.get('table#2 tbody')
  .then($tbody => {
    const rows = $tbody.find('tr')
    return rows.length
  })
  .should('eq', 2)
})
```

[image]

As you can see, this method does work. In the past I've seen problems with badly formatted tables, so it would pay to check the HTML of your table.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't exactly work because for some reason rows.length comes back as 0 even if there are rows - so there's no way to distinguish between the two conditions.

Regarding that the test itself should make sure there are rows...

What I'm actually trying to do is make sure there *aren't* any rows before the test begins - the 'do stuff..' is actually to delete rows if they exist.  The catch-22 is that if there aren't any rows it shouldn't do anything - but it can't know this without dying.

And there's no way to know if someone else has added rows in between tests.

Comment: I can post a working example for you to play with.

Comment: The other thing to ask - what does the page have when first visiting? If there's no rows initially, use `cy.visit()` to clear them. If there are some rows, you can apply `.each()` without failing.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help.  
So I figured out what is going on - the table hasn't entirely loaded when it performs the test - so it comes back with a count of 0 whether there are any rows in the table or not.  If I put a wait in there it usually works.
I know that a visit() is supposed to wait until a page is loaded to start doing things - but it looks like it doesn't necessarily wait until everything is loaded.

Comment: Ok, so initial visit will eventually have some rows - you can use `cy.get('tbody').find('tr').should('have.length', 'gt', 0)` to wait for steady state, eliminating the `if (rows.length)` logic which is a bad smell for testing purposes.